# Is PyObjC pre-installed on OSX SL?

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, pyobjc

I'm going to sell a program that uses that framework in Mac App Store. I want to make sure it will be approved by Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.6
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import objc
>>> objc.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/__init__.pyc'
```

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't installed with Dev Tools?

Comment: 99% sure. Google for "Snow Leopard PyObjC".  Snow Leopard comes with a number of other third-party Python packages installed in the same location.